# How to understand whether a schema is in BCNF

Tags: mysql, normalization, database-normalization, bcnf

I understood the concept of `BCNF` very well so someone gives me a relationship in this format like

```
R = {P, Q, S}
F = {PQ->S, PS->Q, QS->P}
```

I can easily say that the relation is in BCNF since all the keys on left hand side are also super keys. But If I get a real world questions like the below image:
[image]

then how will I determine whether this schema is in `BCNF`? How will I create functional dependencies from the schema and then found out about `super keys`? could anyone give me some pointers to solve such questions?

If you convert the schema into :

```
Code -> City, State
Flightnum -> .....
model -> ...
cid -> ....
Cid, flightnum, date -> ...
```

then obviously this is not in BCNF but the answer is that the following schema is BCNF, and I am not able understood how they derived the equation for it.

Comment: Kindly mention the functional dependencies for your real world question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informally, a schema is in BCNF if all of its relations are in BCNF.

> How will I create functional dependencies from the schema . . .

Without any other context, I'd assume that underlined attributes in the image are attributes in the primary key.

So I'd read that image as saying

```
code->city, state
cid->name, city
etc.
```

Those are your functional dependencies.